# engine will not start - suspect immobiliser

Tags: electronic-control-module

This is my first post on this site. It looks good and the site has a good feel to it so I have some high hopes!
So, I have a 2005 OPEL corsa 3 cyl. and one day it just stopped. I will not bore you with ALL the things I have tried so far - but here is where I am right now : The engine turns over, there is a spark, the camshaft rotates and - get this - when I spray some easy start into the air intake it doesn't even cough !
Am I missing something here - spark + fuel must result in something. I can only conclude that the cam position sensor is giving the wrong timing signal to the ECU.  Can anyone else confirm my suspicion?
thanks

Comment: spark+fuel+compression, of course it must be spark at the right time and proper fuel ratio within the combustion range and minimum compression of about 90psi or higher.

Comment: Do you suspect the immobilizer? Or do you suspect the position sensor? It doesn't sound like the immobilizer although the camshaft position sensor could be a cause. What is the car's recent history before it started? Funny behavior? Repairs or maintenance work? Drive through a big puddle of water? The ignition switch is a possibility too, or a failing ignition coil. Is your check engine light on?

Comment: absolutely no suspicion of any problem in the lead up to this event. I was driving along slowly and then symptom of fuel starvation. No recent maintenance - except - a new key cut as a spare - and I did try it out to see if it worked. This is why I suspect the immobiliser - I think I may have somehow confused it. I will test the compression tomorrow.

Comment: well I just checked the compression and there is none!

Comment: the camshaft rotates - but no compression

Comment: well, when I told you the camshaft was rotating, this was indeed true - however I was only observing the exhaust camshaft (the only one I could see through the oil filler) - you guessed it - the inlet camshaft (the one with the angle sensor!)  is siezed and had sheared the sprocket retaining bolt. Two of the four shaft bearers have suffered damage - I guess through lack of oil but I don't know. The shaft seems to have deposited its material onto the bearers in the head so I am thinking to try to clean off that mess with my dremmel and obtain a new shaft.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know if there is a problem causing this (e.g. blocked oil channel) and if it will happen again after my repair.

Comment: does anyone know how I can check if the oil feed is blocked?

Answer (score 1):

seems being a newbie on this site, i have confused the system. Sorry.
So now I have most of the answer - the inlet camshaft had siezed and this one has the sensor on it hence why the system dissabled the fuel pump and thus sent me off on a wild goose chase!. On first investigation, looking in the oil filler I saw the exhaust camshaft rotating so thought all is well in there- so again another diversion.
Now, my question is - assumong the oil feed is blocked up to the camshaft bearing - how can I clear it?.  With an air line perhaps?
Any ideas?thanks
geoff

Comment: You should only leave an answer to the initial question and post another question.